# Display selected video from gallery as preview

Tags: ios, swift, media-player

Here i use to choose / load video from gallery. And i try to display like preview in screen using imageview. But not able to display my selected video in screen as preview.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices
import AssetsLibrary
import MediaPlayer
import CoreMedia

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var firstAsset: AVAsset?
    var loadingAssetOne = false
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        imagePicker.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func savedPhotosAvailable() -> Bool {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.SavedPhotosAlbum) == false {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Not Available", message: "No Saved Album found", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }



    @IBAction func playvideo(sender: AnyObject) {
        if savedPhotosAvailable() {
            loadingAssetOne = true
            startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)
        }
        }



    func startMediaBrowserFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController, usingDelegate delegate: protocol<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>) -> Bool {
        // 1
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.SavedPhotosAlbum) == false {
            return false
        }

        // 2
        //var mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
         imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
         imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
         imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
         imagePicker.delegate = delegate


        // 3
        presentViewController( imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return true
    }
    // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){


        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imgView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
           imgView.image = pickedImage
        }

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Need to display my video like below image:

[image]

Please help me out. I need to display my selected video as preview, and also if i touch it should play in same screen.And my video which is displaying should like preview of image video like i shown in my above image.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UIView and Create a AVPlayerLayer.

So instead of your imgView create a UIView and set the UIView class to custom class like below.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerView: UIView {

var player: AVPlayer? {
    get {
        return playerLayer.player
    }

    set {
        playerLayer.player = newValue
    }
}

var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
    return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
}

override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}

}
```